# How to compare two times in Ballerina?

Tags: time, ballerina

I want to compare two time string using Ballerina. Bellow is the my approach.

```
 time:Time|error t1 = time:parse("2017-06-26T09:46:22.444-0500",
                                    "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");

 time:Time|error t2 = time:parse("2017-06-25T09:46:22.444-0500",
                                    "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");

    if (t1 is time:Time && t2 is time: Time){
        if (t1 < t2){
            io: println("t2 is greater");
        }
    }
```

But I got error `operator '<' not defined for 'ballerina/time:Time'.` Is there are any way to compare two times in Ballerina?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
time:Time|error t1 = time:parse("2019-06-23T09:46:21.441-0500", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
time:Time|error t2 = time:parse("2018-06-25T09:46:22.445-0500", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");

if (t1 is time:Time && t2 is time: Time) {
   if (t1.time < t2.time) {
      io:println("t2 is greater");
   } else {
      io:println("t1 is greater");
   }
}
```